# ChromeDriver with headless chromium : Check failed: IsSupportedClipboardBuffer(buffer)

Tags: aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, google-chrome-headless, docker-image

I want to create an AWS DockerImageFunction with headless chromium for running my test scenarios (behave + selenium + python).

- The chrome version is: 89.0.4389.128
- ChromeDriver version is: 89.0.4389.23
- Selenium version: 3.141.0

Environment:

- RedHat Linux
- Docker container

One problem occurred, which I cannot solve recently.

When I try to send keys to an input field, which located in a modal on our website, the ChromeDriver crashes.

The problem can be triggered with the following code snippet:

```
input_field = self.driver.wait.for_clickability_of_element(MOBILE_NUM_INPUT)
input_field.focus()
input_field.click()
input_field.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
input_field.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
input_field.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD1)
input_field.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD0)
```

After one "LEFT" commands the "Keys.NUMPAD1" was executed with no problem. But when I try to send multiple "LEFT" commands, the webdriver crashes.

The input field looks like the picture below:

[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvLu4.png)

This input field has animation, but I tried to wait until it's finished but it wasn't enough to solve the problem

The ChromeDriver log shows the following:

```
lambda_1  | [1624797899.659][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Input.dispatchKeyEvent (id=1263) 37EEB46F526E1B95F6DDDC7454E78A14 {
lambda_1  |    "code": "Numpad1",
lambda_1  |    "isKeypad": true,
lambda_1  |    "key": "1",
lambda_1  |    "modifiers": 0,
lambda_1  |    "text": "1",
lambda_1  |    "type": "keyDown",
lambda_1  |    "unmodifiedText": "1",
lambda_1  |    "windowsVirtualKeyCode": 97
lambda_1  | }
lambda_1  | [0627/124459.630384:FATAL:headless_clipboard.cc(296)] Check failed: IsSupportedClipboardBuffer(buffer).
```

The used chrome flags are the following:

```
options.binary_location = '/opt/bin/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
options.add_argument('--use-system-clipboard')
options.add_argument('--allow-no-sandbox-job')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

Comment: Found a solution:

 AWS created a Dockerfile with the related option flags too (python + selenium)

[link](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-ui-testing-using-selenium/blob/main/Dockerfile)

The FFmpeg tracing was not needed for us (docker build was much quicker ~5min)

One more option flag needs to be added :

"--disable-gpu-sandbox"

Comment: I am facing a similar error in chromium headless with puppeteer - "Check failed: IsSupportedClipboardBuffer(buffer)." Any clue what causes this crash? TIA

Comment: Sadly I didn't try puppeteer